# Can/should probability estimates be calculated on the whole dataset and not just on the test set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models

For a binary classification problem on a dataset X, divided in train and test sets (or train, validation, test if performing parameter tuning), one can get probability estimates by fitting the model on training set, and then using the `predict_proba` method (if available) on the test set. In this way, one can get probability estimates for the unseen data.

However what is the best way to obtain probability estimates on whole dataset - if this makes sense, which does not involve training on the whole dataset X and then use `predict_proba(X)`?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean how to make both in-sample and out-of-sample predictions based on a particular predictive model? If so, what is there to this beyond “make the predictions”? Do you mean how to program this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with [cross validation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eschneide/tut5/node42.html)?

A straightforward alternative to splitting your data set once (into training and test sets) is to divide it into K equal subsets. You then use each of these in turn as the test set and the other K-1 subsets as the training set, i.e. you need to fit the model K times. This is known as K-fold cross validation.

Comment: I’m not seeing how this answers the question.